# About arguments by default in C++

Tags: c++

I am asking help to understand:
- In this program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int j = 0;
    int k = 1;
    int m = -1;
    int n = 1;

    int p = ((j * 300) - (4 * n) - (7 * m)); 

    if (int l = ((j * 300) - (4 * n) - (7 * m)) > 0) {
        std::cout << "l is egual: " << l - 1 << std::endl;
    }   
    else {
        std::cout << "l is negative: " << l << std::endl;
    }

    if (p > 0) {
        std::cout << "p is egual: " << p - 1 << std::endl;
    }   
    else {
        std::cout << "p is negative: " << p << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I got the output:
gcc circonfEn.cc -lstdc++ -o circonfEn
./circonfEn
l is egual: 0
p is egual: 2

Why the instruction in the if do not work?

Comment: It's thé boolean operation that gets into l. You get int l = 2>0 then l=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int l = ((j * 300) - (4 * n) - (7 * m)) > 0 // true;
l = 1; // because true == 1;
1 - 1 = 0; // so, l is egual: 0;
```

Do you understand?

Comment: Yes I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Your code essentially means (modulo the scope of `l`):

```
int l = ((j * 300) - (4 * n) - (7 * m)) > 0;
if (l != 0) {
    std::cout << "l is egual: " << l - 1 << std::endl;
}   
else {
    std::cout << "l is negative: " << l << std::endl;
}
```

Since `>` returns a `bool`, the value of `l` is always `0` or `1`.

The code should be rewritten as:

```
int l = (j * 300) - (4 * n) - (7 * m);
if (l > 0) {
    std::cout << "l is egual: " << l - 1 << std::endl;
}   
else {
    std::cout << "l is negative: " << l << std::endl;
}
```

Or:

```
if (int l = (j * 300) - (4 * n) - (7 * m); l > 0) {
    std::cout << "l is egual: " << l - 1 << std::endl;
}   
else {
    std::cout << "l is negative: " << l << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Anybody who tries the last solution, make sure your compiler is in C++17 mode.

Answer (score 2):

Defining variables in the condition of an `if` statement is a little known feature. I'm afraid you are not using it as prescribed. You see, when you write:

```
if (int l = <whatever>)
```

Then it's the same as if you've written

```
int l = <whatever>;
if(l)
```

`l` itself is evaluated for truthiness. You can't specify it needs to be evaluated as `l > 0`. So when you write:

```
int l = ((j * 300) - (4 * n) - (7 * m)) > 0
```

`l` will be either 0 or 1. Because you initialize it with `((j * 300) - (4 * n) - (7 * m)) > 0`